# Eclipse C++ resume executes next line

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, resume

When debugging my C++ code in Eclipse, I press the Resume button (or hit F8) and the next line of code is executed. Should this not continue to execute the code until my next breakpoint?

Comment: Maybe the marked breakpoint is not reached?

Comment: If I keep pressing the resume button it skips to the next line until it reaches the breakpoint.